# How can I provide the SSH user passwords for a set of hosts in ansible using vault

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-vault

Considering the following Ansible `hosts` file:

```
[webservers]        
server1.example.com ansible_ssh_pass=1234567
server2.example.com ansible_ssh_pass=2345678
server3.example.com ansible_ssh_pass=3456789
```

I would like to include these password values from a vault file and have a `hosts` file like (my intention is to have an `ini` inventory format):

```
[webservers]        
server1.example.com ansible_ssh_pass={{ ssh_pass }}
server2.example.com ansible_ssh_pass={{ ssh_pass }}
server3.example.com ansible_ssh_pass={{ ssh_pass }}
```

where the `sss_pass` variable comes from vaulted files defined in `host_vars` folder.

The relevant ansible folder structure looks like this:

```
playbook.yml
inventories/
  atlanta/
    group_vars/
    hosts
    host_vars/
      server1.example.com
      server2.example.com
      server3.example.com
```

But ansible is complaining:

```
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /root/hsm-ansible-deploy/inventories/atlanta/hosts with ini plugin: /root/hsm-ansible-deploy/inventories/atlanta/hosts:18: Expected key=value host variable assignment, got: ssh_pass
```

- Why do I get the error?
- How can I import passwords into the `hosts` file?

Comment: This is a typo. Space character is a separator. Use quotes or delete spaces.　Listed questions are irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks! Indded syntax error. Also I found another solution where the `ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ ssh_pass }}"` can actually be defined in `group_vars` then the `hosts` file is even cleaner.

Comment: OK, I rephrased the questions and gave an answer based on your indication and my findings. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

As indicated by @techraf this is only a syntax issue. The correct way of writing the ini `hosts` file is:

```
[webservers]        
server1.example.com ansible_ssh_pass="{{ ssh_pass }}"
server2.example.com ansible_ssh_pass="{{ ssh_pass }}"
server3.example.com ansible_ssh_pass="{{ ssh_pass }}"
```

But I also found a more elegant solution where the `hosts` file is even more elegant, by not providing the `ansible_ssh_pass` variable at all in `hosts`:

```
[webservers]        
server1.example.com
server2.example.com
server3.example.com
```

and using the `group_vars/all` to define this variable there:

```
---
ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ vault_ansible_ssh_pass }}"
```

where `vault_ansible_ssh_pass` is defined in each of the hosts secrets vaulted files like `host_vars/server1.example.com`

```
---
vault_ansible_ssh_pass: "my secret password"
```

and then these files are encrypted using `ansible-vault`:

```
ansible-vault encrypt inventories/atlanta/host_vars/server*/vault --vault-password-file ~/.vault_pass.txt
```

where `~/.vault_pass.txt` contains in clear text the ansible vault password.

Comment: Why not having the variable in each `host_vars` file simply called `ansible_ssh_pass`? This way the even the group var would be unnecessary.